# Warning HHH000444 do Hibernate usando Oracle 10g com WildFly 8.0.0 - follow-on locking

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, oracle10g

Ao fazer algumas consultas em uma view usando **JPA (2.1) com Hibernate**, estou tendo esse *warning*. Apesar de estar funcionando e ser somente um *warning*, isso me incomoda um pouco.

> WARN org.hibernate.loader.Loader - HHH000444: Encountered request for
>   locking however dialect reports that database prefers locking be done
>   in a separate select (follow-on locking); results will be locked after
>   initial query execute

Isso ocorre no seguinte ambiente:

- JPA 2.1 / Hibernate 4.3.0.Final;
- WildFly 8.0.0.Final;
- Oracle DB 10g;

Além disso, fazendo pesquisas sobre esse warning, cheguei até um **[bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8135)** para o pessoal do Hibernate que acabou sendo **rejeitado**. No bug, **o problema também parece ocorrer no Oracle 11g**.

Como corrigir ou evitar esse warning?

Answer (score 2):

O `warning` ocorre porquê o lock no mesmo query por padrão está desligado. E foi desligado para o Oracle dado limitações do mesmo em conseguir fazer select for update em diversas situações, principalmente com queries envolvendo paginação (que no oracle 10 precisa de rownum + order by).

Se você não faz lock em queries com paginação, pode voltar o comportamento no dialect. Se usa, mude seu query de modo a fazer primeiro o lock em um query separado, ou use native query.

O comportamento padrão do hibernate nesse caso representa um erro, pois o lock a-posteriori do segundo select representa um problema de concorrência, pois o registro pode ter sido mudado entre os dois selects e os dados usados no primeiro vão estar diferentes do esperado

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se isso pode ser considerado um defeito ou não. Mas o que acontece, é que no dialeto implementado pelo Hibernate para bases Oracle (`org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`), está retornando `true` no método que informa o uso do `useFollowOnLocking`. Isso acaba gerando o warning. Não me pergunte o que faz o `followOnLocking`, porque não sei ainda.

**Para suprimir o problema**, precisamos criar uma classe que extenda a classe org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect e devemos sobrescrever o método `public boolean useFollowOnLocking()` para retornar `false`.

Sendo assim, a classe ficaria assim:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;

public class MeuDialetoOracle10g extends Oracle10gDialect {

    @Override
    public boolean useFollowOnLocking() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Após isso, basta você declarar esse dialeto para ser usado no **persistence.xml**:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="br.com.meu.pacote.MeuDialetoOracle10g"/>
```

E pronto. O *warning* vai embora.

Comment: Honestamente, "criar" um dialeto próprio para esconder um warning? E quando o erro realmente acontecer? Isso aí nunca vai aparecer no LOG e horas e horas serão perdidas procurando por um erro que não é mais exibido.

Comment: Acredito que um erro não ocorreria, porque o padrão do followOnLocking é `false`. P/ o Oracle está `true`. Talvez eu perca uma funcionalidade. Isso começa a ocorrer após a atualização do Hibernate p/ a versão 4.2.0, onde o dialeto do Oracle8i que é pai dos dialetos do 9i e do 10g mudou o método `useFollowOnLocking()` para retornar `true`. No entanto, o default, segundo a própria documentação, é `false`.

Comment: Logo, tudo indica que parece ser mais uma mensagem incorreta do que um problema. Existe [**uma discussão**](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1025404) no fórum do hibernate sobre isso.

Comment: Novamente, o que vai acontecer quando realmente um problema acontecer?

Comment: Mas qual é o problema que poderia acontecer?

Comment: Encountered request for locking however dialect reports that database prefers locking be done in a separate select (follow-on locking); results will be locked after initial query execute

Comment: Imagine no dia que a configuração default não estiver ativa no banco de dados...

Comment: Pesquisando um pouco mais, verifiquei que o useFollowOnLocking está relacionado ao uso de pessimistic ou optimistic lock. Então se for usar pessimitic locking, `useFollowOnLocking = false`. Se for optimistic locking então `useFollowOnLocking = true`. Vai depender da abordagem do seu projeto.

Comment: Desculpe, mas olhe só o que sua solução propoe. Depois a perfomance do servidor vai pro chão pois estão usando algo que não deveria e não será avisado no warning.

Comment: Qual solução para o problema você sugere?

Comment: Ignorar o log. 3 linhas de um warning não afeta em nada.

Comment: Não são três linhas. É uma linha para cada linha retornada em um query feita pelo hibernate search. Então, se o que se está indexando com HS é uma tabela com 5000 linhas, são 5000 warnings. Em todo caso, postei **[uma questão no SO em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712195/hibernate-warning-about-follow-on-locking-using-oracle-10g)** sobre esse caso.

Comment: Você poderia mudar o tipo de warning logado via log4j. ou entaõ determinar outro arquivo para que todo o log do hibernate fosse salvo. Milhares de outras opções que não 'mascarariam' quando o problema real acontecer.

Comment: Atualizando... Realmente esse logging não deveria acontecer segundo [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712195/hibernate-warning-about-follow-on-locking-using-oracle-10g) no SO e um novo [bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9097) no Hibernate foi aberto.